# How to approach to the recursive sequence in this question

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to reduce this sequence to something more understandable.

The recursive function is defined as

$ x(0) = 0 \\ 
x(i) = \frac{x(i-1)+ x(i+1)}{2} +1 \text{  for  } i = 1 \dots n-1 \\
x(n) = x(n-1) +1 $.

This is a part of larger question and a solution suggests that it is easy to observe that $x(1)=2n-1 , x(2)=4n-4 , x(i) = 2in-i^2$.

My question is "how?".

Comment: Obviously there should be a "+" instead of \cdot in the recursion for x(i).

Comment: Sorry about that. Corrected

Comment: Are you sure about your function definitions? From the $x(n)$ definition, we can claim $x(i+1) = x(i-1) + 2$ and plug into the $x(i)$ definition to produce a contradiction.

Comment: The larger question suggestion implies that $x(i) = n^2 - (n-i)^2$

Comment: You are right. I should have added that the equation x(i) is true when $i \in \{1,\dots, n-1\} $